# Using my laptop from Slovakia to connect to my home broadband in UK

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn

I work for a government client in UK but my children are in Slovakia. My office network can only be accessed through a company provided VPN. If I am connecting to my home broadband in Slovakia, my office picks up my location, and there are chances of me getting fired.is there a way I can connect to my broadband in Slovakia, which will then connect to my broadband in UK, after which I can connect to my office VPN? This will show my location as UK. I am afraid, I have to quit my hard earned job if this is not possible. Please can anyone advice and help?

Comment: Sure just throw in more VPN. However, I’m voting to close anyway because what kind of question even is this.

Comment: We need more details: is it your personal laptop or your company's laptop? Do you have admin privileges on the laptop? How precisely do you connect to the VPN (preconfigured application installed by your company, or manual configuration by yourself, or whatever...)?

Comment: I think the relevant security institutions would not only take a dim view of this, but you would also open yourself to prosecution, not just being fired. This is especially so if you are trying to circumvent it. You _really_ need to take this up with your IT department.

Comment: Thanks all. In fact, my office laptop has a VPN application, which I have to log in first, in order to access any of the servers, intranet, etc. I do not have the facility of have a computer at home and keep it running for 24x7. I was looking at some of the routers available, with VPN. Nethgear, Linksys, etc. it says on the description that there is VPN built-in, but I don’t know how they work. Any suggestions? By the way, which are the expensive and best quality VPNs?

Comment: Before buying some equipement you should first experiment with any reliable VPN service (some of them offer a trial period). Configuring another VPN along with your company VPN will be tricky and I have no idea how to do that (but I'm no VPN specialist). You will have to connect first to the VPN Slovakia->UK, then to your company VPN that would be tunneled in the other one, without overiding it. Configuring all of this is very probably impossible if don't have administration privileges on your PC...

Comment: I maybe misunderstood the way you would use a router+VPN. I had in mind a VPN server on a router that would be located in the UK. The other way is a router that can be configured to connect to a VPN service: the router would be in Slovakia, and the VPN service in the UK (or anythere else as as long as it offers public IP adresses in the UK). You would connect your office laptop to this router. There are possible variations, as any other device (PC, phone, tablet...) could replace the dedicated router...

Answer (score 0):

An additional VPN ( Slovakia -> UK ) will help you with your needs. Also keep in mind that most of VPN services have the "Kill Switch" feature - basically it is an advanced security measure that prevents your data from leaking to the web, by continuously monitoring your connection to the remote server.

However, if your concerns are about your IP getting logged, try to avoid free/cheap VPN Services as their public IPs are well-known and you could be exposed easily.

To mitigate this risk, another approach could be to use some Remote Control applications (such as Team Viewer or Anydesk, just to name some) but you will need a target computer on the other end (UK) always on and connected to the internet. In this way the VPN connection to the office would be entirely managed by the target computer and your Slovakian IP won't get leaked.

I hope this satisfied your request.

Comment: NordVPN is an example of a cheap VPN service, you'd have a commonly used UK IP, and it has a feature that will kill traffic if you get disconnected from the VPN to keep any traffic hitting the endpoint with your actual IP. OpenVPN could also be a good option if you want a private one using your home IP, but you'd need a computer set up at your home in the UK to receive connections. There are also other options like using a VPN router that could let you first connect to your home VPN and then onward to your work VPN. Keep in mind that using dual VPNs will be much slower.

Comment: Thanks all. In fact, my office laptop has a VPN application, which I have to log in first, in order to access any of the servers, intranet, etc. I do not have the facility of have a computer at home and keep it running for 24x7. I was looking at some of the routers available, with VPN. Nethgear, Linksys, etc. it says on the description that there is VPN built-in, but I don’t know how they work. Any suggestions? By the way, which are the expensive and best quality VPNs?